# Convert String in Host byte order (Little endian) to Network byte order (Big endian)

Tags: php, string, hex, endianness

I have a Hex String which reads `18000000` this String is in Host byte order (Little endian) and I need to convert it to Network byte order (Big endian). The resultant Hex String will be `00000018`.

**To summarize I need to convert**
`18000000 to 00000018`

How do I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried strrev() but I get `00000081`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pack` / `unpack` functions to convert endianness:

```
/**
 * Convert $endian hex string to specified $format
 * 
 * @param string $endian Endian HEX string
 * @param string $format Endian format: 'N' - big endian, 'V' - little endian
 * 
 * @return string 
 */
function formatEndian($endian, $format = 'N') {
    $endian = intval($endian, 16);      // convert string to hex
    $endian = pack('L', $endian);       // pack hex to binary sting (unsinged long, machine byte order)
    $endian = unpack($format, $endian); // convert binary sting to specified endian format

    return sprintf("%'.08x", $endian[1]); // return endian as a hex string (with padding zero)
}

$endian = '18000000';
$big    = formatEndian($endian, 'N'); // string "00000018"
$little = formatEndian($endian, 'V'); // string "18000000"
```

To learn more about `pack` format take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this answer while searching for something, but I ended up doing something a lot simpler (since I knew my string was always going to have a leading zero if necessary to align to a two character boundary):

```
$littlendian = join(array_reverse(str_split($bigendian, 2))));
```

Obviously if your bigendian input isn't well formatted like that, this trick isn't going to work directly :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result=bin2hex( implode( array_reverse( str_split( hex2bin($src) ) ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
$input = 18000000;  

$length=strlen((string)$input);
$sum=0;
$numbers="";
while ($length>0) {     
    $number = $input % 10;
    $numbers.= $number;        
    $input = $input/10;
    $length--;
}
echo $numbers;
```

Comment: This solution will not work for HEX strings (`0A0B0C0D` string will produce an error)