# How to convert hex to int32?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to convert hex code from 010 Editor to int.
[010 Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXsmd.jpg)

How can I get 4118 by converting string 16100000?
I tried hexdec function, but It gives the wrong result.

```
echo hexdec('1610'); //gives 5648

echo hexdec('16100000'); //gives 370147328
```

And how to convert back 4118 to 16100000?

Comment: The hex representation there is called "little endian". See also: [`unpack`](http://php.net/unpack)/[`pack`](http://php.net/pack), perhaps [`hex2bin`](http://php.net/hex2bin) etc.

Comment: `echo hexdec(bin2hex(implode(array_reverse(str_split(hex2bin('16100000'))))));` more solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828024/convert-string-in-host-byte-order-little-endian-to-network-byte-order-big-end

Comment: mario, Felippe Duarte thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That hex to int32 convertion in the 010 Editor you've mentioned has little endian sequencing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

So, you have to assemble your original hexadecimal string in inverse order.

```php
echo hexdec('00001016');  // Would result in the 4118 you were expecting.
```

And to have it back you can use base_convert, from base 10 to base 16 and rearenge the string:

```
echo base_convert('00004118', 10, 16);
```

Which would give you '1016'